# Can't install CentOS on Virtual box

Tags: centos, virtualbox

I've never had this problem before, I've build multiple VMs on my pc, and they all work. Today, when I try to deploy a new VM, it starts like normal, but ends with this:

```
[<FFFFFFFF81c28929>] ? error +0x0/0x17
[<FFFFFFFF8100C200>] ? child_rip+0x0/0x20
```

It wont boot off the net install disk.

I have tried using a different ISO. I was doing CentOS 6.4 and tried Centos 6.5. Anyone seen this before?

Comment: Any particular reason for the downvotes?

Comment: I thought your question was decent, but maybe they are trying to help you achieve the Peer Pressure badge?

Comment: @Jeff Your question has *no* useful troubleshooting data. There's no possible way we could even guess at possible causes here. (I *know* what was wrong because I read your answer, but there's no way we would be able to get to that conclusion from this data...)

Comment: Welcome to the world of the question asker... I had no information my self.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I feel foolish. Some how I managed to slide the memory for the system to 192 MB. That was not enough for the picky CentOS operating system.

Comment: It happens to the best of us.  I think you can close your question to avoid getting downvoted further, it will probably be closed by a mod regardless.